# Make the REPL output the name of a record type?

Tags: purescript

From [section 3.11 of Purescript By Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-curried-functions):

[image: screenshot]

However, when I try the same in my REPL I get:

[image: REPL]

That is, it output the literal representation, rather than the name of the type,  `Entry`.  Do I need to configure the REPL somehow to behave as the book does?

Comment: I think the book is either incorrect or is using a much older version of repl.

Comment: thanks.  related question: how do i `show` the type of a variable?  not in the REPL, but just in code?

Comment: That is not possible. Types are completely erased during compilation, they do not exist at all during runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the types show by name, you need a type constructor instead of a type alias.

```
pulp repl
> import Data.Record.ShowRecord   -- from "purescript-record-show"

> data Address = Address {street :: String, city :: String, state :: String}

> address = Address {street: "main", city: "SanFran", state: "CA"}

> instance showAddress :: Show Address where show (Address rec) = "Address " <> showRecord rec

> address
Address { city: "SanFran", state: "CA", street: "main" }

> :t address
Address
```